# Is there some kind of implementation or DOM I need?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm taking a beginner javascript/html/css course and don't have a super strong background in these. I'm trying to make a page that simulates a simple card game for a user versus the computer. The game takes digits that correspond to a card's suit and value and then displays them on the screen. Whoever has the higher card wins and a message is displayed.

This involves some things I'm not clear on, such as simple formatting or making the functions work together. I'm especially confused on where to put DOMs and how to even get a startbutton to work.

I'm using four functions:
randomizer
getcard
startgame
comparecard

In what ways can I make these interact with eachother? Are there any formatting issues in the css, html, etc.? Below is my initial code, I've tried too many variations and I'm just missing something I can't spot.

```js
function randomizer(x) {
  var y = x * Math.random();
  var randNum = Math.round(y);
  return randNum;

}

function getcard() {
  var suit = randomizer(3);
  var card = randomizer(13);
  var wholeCard = suit + " " + card;

  return wholeCard;

}

function startgame() {
  var usercard;
  var computercard;
  usercard.getcard();
  document.getElementByID("yourcard").innerHTML = usercard;
  computercard.getcard();
  document.getElementByID("computercard").innerHTML = computercard;

}

function comparecard() {
  var usercard;
  var computercard;
  var winnermessage;
  var usernum;
  var computernum;


  if (usernum > computernum) {
    winnermessage = "You Win!";
  } else if (usernum < computernum) {
    winnermessage = "The Computer Wins!";
  } else {
    winnermessage = "It's a Tie!";
  }



}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cardcontain {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

[class*="cardgrid"] {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardgrid {
  color: #aa4444;
}

.cardgrid2 {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #651e1e;
  height: 110px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.cardgrid3 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #888888;
}

button {
  background-color: #57ac75;
}

.winner::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  height: 400px;
}

.winner {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #3f7a3b;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontain">
  <h2 class="cardgrid">Computer Card</h2>
  <h2 class="cardgrid">Your Card</h2>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardgrid2" id="computercard"></div>
  <div class="cardgrid2" id="yourcard"></div>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardgrid">
    <p> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cardgrid"><button onclick="startgame()">Click here for your card</button></div>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardgrid3">
    <h3>Key: first digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>0 = Spade</li>
      <li>1 = Club</li>
      <li>2 = Heart</li>
      <li>3 = Diamond</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cardgrid3">
    <h3>Key: second digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>11 = Jack</li>
      <li>12 = Queen</li>
      <li>13 = King</li>
      <li>14 = Ace</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="winner" id="winner"></p>
```

Comment: It not *terrible* but you seem confused about how JavaScript works. `var usercard; usercard.getcard();` -- what exactly are you expecting here?

Comment: I should definitely point out your "randomizer" is bad. It generates half as many 0s and max values as it should. Always use `Math.floor(Math.random()*range)` to ensure proper distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points

- `getcard` probably needs to return the suit & value separately, as you need just the value to compare later on
- Javascript is case sensitive so `getElementByID` is wrong (it is `getElementById`)
- Where you had code like `var usercard;` and `usercard.getcard();` makes no sense. `getcard()` is a standalone function which just returns a value so you probably wanted `var usercard = getcard();`
- There are a bunch of other things which you will learn as you get better at javascript too broad for this answer

The below works along the lines I expect you thought

```js
function randomizer(x) {
  var y = x * Math.random();
  var randNum = Math.round(y);
  return randNum;

}

function getcard() {
  var suit = randomizer(3);
  var card = randomizer(13);
  
  return {suit, card};

}

function startgame() {
  var usercard = getcard();
  var computercard = getcard();
  document.getElementById("yourcard").innerHTML = usercard.suit + " " + usercard.card;
  document.getElementById("computercard").innerHTML = computercard.suit + " " + computercard.card;
  comparecard(usercard.card, computercard.card)
}

function comparecard(usernum, computernum) {
  
  if (usernum > computernum) {
    winnermessage = "You Win!";
  } else if (usernum < computernum) {
    winnermessage = "The Computer Wins!";
  } else {
    winnermessage = "It's a Tie!";
  }
  document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = winnermessage;


}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cardcontain {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

[class*="cardgrid"] {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardgrid {
  color: #aa4444;
}

.cardgrid2 {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #651e1e;
  height: 110px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.cardgrid3 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #888888;
}

button {
  background-color: #57ac75;
}

.winner::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  height: 400px;
}

.winner {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #3f7a3b;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontain">
  <h2 class="cardgrid">Computer Card</h2>
  <h2 class="cardgrid">Your Card</h2>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardgrid2" id="computercard"></div>
  <div class="cardgrid2" id="yourcard"></div>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardgrid">
    <p> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cardgrid"><button onclick="startgame()">Click here for your card</button></div>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardgrid3">
    <h3>Key: first digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>0 = Spade</li>
      <li>1 = Club</li>
      <li>2 = Heart</li>
      <li>3 = Diamond</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cardgrid3">
    <h3>Key: second digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>11 = Jack</li>
      <li>12 = Queen</li>
      <li>13 = King</li>
      <li>14 = Ace</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="winner" id="winner"></p>
```

Note: I have not fixed your `randomizer` but if you're generating playing cards I dont think you want to generate zeros... also if were going for realism you need to ensure the computer and player cant randomly pick the same card.